# Extremely simple virtual machine in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler, virtual-machine

I wrote a very simple VM to get a bit more familiar with Rust. The VM architecture was not the focus, so that I think that can safely ignored. Is my code idiomatic and clean? I felt that I was very repetitive in some areas, namely the implementation of the binary operations.

Code:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Literal {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
    Str(&'static str),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Instruction {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
    Push(Literal),
    Dsp,
}

struct Machine {
    stack: Vec<Literal>,
    code: Vec<Instruction>,
    ip: usize,
}

impl Machine {
    fn new(code: Vec<Instruction>) -> Machine {
        Machine {
            stack: Vec::new(),
            code,
            ip: 0,
        }
    }

    fn add_instr(&mut self, instr: Instruction) {
        self.code.push(instr);
    }

    fn push(&mut self, x: Literal) {
        self.stack.push(x);
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Literal {
        self.stack.pop().expect("stack popped while empty")
    }

    fn execute(&mut self) {
        while self.ip < self.code.len() {
            let opcode = self.code[self.ip];
            self.ip += 1;
            self.dispatch(opcode);
        }
    }

    fn dispatch(&mut self, opcode: Instruction) {
        match opcode {
            Instruction::Push(lit) => self.push(lit),
            Instruction::Add => {
                let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
                self.push(match pair {
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Int(x + y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x + y),
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x as f32 + y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Float(x + y as f32),
                    _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
                });
            }
            Instruction::Sub => {
                let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
                self.push(match pair {
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Int(x - y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x - y),
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x as f32 - y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Float(x - y as f32),
                    _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
                });
            }
            Instruction::Mul => {
                let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
                self.push(match pair {
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Int(x * y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x * y),
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x as f32 * y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Float(x * y as f32),
                    _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
                });
            }
            Instruction::Div => {
                let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
                self.push(match pair {
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Int(x / y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x / y),
                    (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(x as f32 / y),
                    (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Float(x / y as f32),
                    _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
                });
            }
            Instruction::Dsp => {
                match self.pop() {
                    Literal::Int(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                    Literal::Float(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                    Literal::Str(x) => print!("{}", x),
                }
                io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
            }
        };
    }

    fn dump_stack(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", self.stack)
    }

    fn dump_code(&self) -> String {
        self.code
            .iter()
            .map(|x| format!("{:?}", x))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("\n")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut machine = Machine::new(vec![
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Float(2.)),
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Int(1)),
        Instruction::Div,
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Str("1 / 2 is ")),
        Instruction::Dsp,
        Instruction::Dsp,
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Str("\n")),
        Instruction::Dsp
    ]);
    println!("------------  dumped code   ------------");
    println!("{}", machine.dump_code());
    println!("------------ machine output ------------");
    machine.execute();
}
```

This outputs:

```
------------  dumped code   ------------
Push(Float(2.0))
Push(Int(1))
Div
Push(Str("1 / 2 is "))
Dsp
Dsp
Push(Str("\n"))
Dsp
------------ machine output ------------
1 / 2 is 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the repetition by extracting the common logic into a function like so:

```
fn math(&mut self, float_fn: impl Fn(f32, f32) -> f32, int_fn: impl Fn(i32, i32) -> i32) {
            let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
            self.push(match pair {
                (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Int(int_fn(x,y)),
                (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(float_fn(x,y)),
                (Literal::Int(x), Literal::Float(y)) => Literal::Float(float_fn(x as f32,  y)),
                (Literal::Float(x), Literal::Int(y)) => Literal::Float(float_fn(x, y as f32)),
                _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
            });
} 

fn dispatch(&mut self, opcode: Instruction) {
    match opcode {
        Instruction::Push(lit) => self.push(lit),
        Instruction::Add => self.math(|x,y| x+y, |x,y| x+y),
        Instruction::Sub => self.math(|x,y| x-y, |x,y| x-y),
        Instruction::Mul => self.math(|x,y| x*y, |x,y| x*y),
        Instruction::Div => self.math(|x,y| x/y, |x,y| x/y),
        Instruction::Dsp => {
            match self.pop() {
                Literal::Int(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                Literal::Float(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                Literal::Str(x) => print!("{}", x),
            }
            io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't much you can do with this repetition.

Rust does not have any kind of coercion. I don't think you could use trait objects, either.

Here is my approach that is a bit more idiomatic.

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Literal {
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32),
    Str(&'static str),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Instruction {
    BinaryOp(Op),
    Push(Literal),
    Dsp,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Op {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Mul,
    Div,
}

struct Machine {
    stack: Vec<Literal>,
    code: Vec<Instruction>,
    ip: usize,
}

impl Machine {
    fn new(code: Vec<Instruction>) -> Machine {
        Machine {
            stack: Vec::new(),
            code,
            ip: 0,
        }
    }

    fn add_instr(&mut self, instr: Instruction) {
        self.code.push(instr);
    }

    fn push(&mut self, x: Literal) {
        self.stack.push(x);
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Literal {
        self.stack.pop().expect("stack popped while empty")
    }

    fn execute(&mut self) {
        while self.ip < self.code.len() {
            let opcode = self.code[self.ip];
            self.ip += 1;
            self.dispatch(opcode);
        }
    }

    fn dispatch(&mut self, opcode: Instruction) {
        use Literal::*;

        match opcode {
            Instruction::Push(lit) => self.push(lit),
            Instruction::BinaryOp(op) => {
                let pair = (self.pop(), self.pop());
                let coerced = match pair {
                    (Int(x), Int(y)) => pair,
                    (Float(x), Float(y)) => pair,
                    (Int(x), Float(y)) => (Float(x as f32), Float(y)),
                    (Float(x), Int(y)) => (Float(x), Float(y as f32)),
                    _ => panic!("error in code-- expected int/float for binary operations"),
                };
                let result = match (op, coerced.0, coerced.1) {
                    (Op::Add, Int(x), Int(y)) => Int(x + y),
                    (Op::Add, Float(x), Float(y)) => Float(x + y),
                    (Op::Sub, Int(x), Int(y)) => Int(x - y),
                    (Op::Sub, Float(x), Float(y)) => Float(x - y),
                    (Op::Mul, Int(x), Int(y)) => Int(x * y),
                    (Op::Mul, Float(x), Float(y)) => Float(x * y),
                    (Op::Div, Int(x), Int(y)) => Int(x / y),
                    (Op::Div, Float(x), Float(y)) => Float(x / y),
                    _ => unreachable!(),
                };
                self.push(result);
            }
            Instruction::Dsp => {
                match self.pop() {
                    Int(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                    Float(x) => print!("{:?}", x),
                    Str(x) => print!("{}", x),
                }
                io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
            }
        };
    }

    fn dump_stack(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", self.stack)
    }

    fn dump_code(&self) -> String {
        self.code
            .iter()
            .map(|x| format!("{:?}", x))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("\n")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut machine = Machine::new(vec![
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Float(2.)),
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Int(1)),
        Instruction::BinaryOp(Op::Div),
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Str("1 / 2 is ")),
        Instruction::Dsp,
        Instruction::Dsp,
        Instruction::Push(Literal::Str("\n")),
        Instruction::Dsp
    ]);
    println!("------------  dumped code   ------------");
    println!("{}", machine.dump_code());
    println!("------------ machine output ------------");
    machine.execute();
}
```